# Reinstall PHP Pear

Tags: php, macos, phpunit, pear, macports

I used to have MAMP (http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). Uninstalled that and installed "MAMP" via Macports.

I completely removed /Applications/MAMP/ folders. I would now like to install PHPUnit via pear.

Pear is installed:

```
> which pear
/opt/local/bin/pear

> pear config-show
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    <not set>
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /private/tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/pear
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /opt/local/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          <not set>
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /opt/local/etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/*removed*/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /opt/local/etc/pear.conf
```

There are lots of references to /Applications/MAMP/ folder structure which I had deleted (and mysteriously keeps regenerating). I would like to remove all these references but not sure what substitute values should be. I cannot seem to uninstall pear or upgrade pear.

Ideally I would like a situation where pear remains installed and PHPUnit is installed so that I can run some tests.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust those config values with `pear config-set`, for example

```
$ pear config-set php_dir /usr/share/pear/php
$ pear config-set data_dir /usr/share/pear/data
```

Do that for all config values with "broken" paths.

After that, either manually move the files from the old to the new directories, or reinstall all packages.

Comment: I had a different issue then this, but your solution helped me out.  thanks.

Comment: there was conflicting installed of pear and the config was messed up and pointing to the wrong location.  also, the files needed to execute  extensions like phpunit were not in the bin to be used from the command line.  anyway, this helped me out and now my install is all setup.  i guess this kind of stuff happens when you have mamp and zend server and OSXs built in php at the same time.